# ract-native app not updating when edit the content to display

Tags: reactjs, mobile, native

I have created a react-native app and I have executed after lots of trials. But when i'm editing the content of the app. It is taking time or not updating the content what i have changed on App. Please could you help me on this.

Comment: are you using the state variables for changing the content?

Comment: I have changed the code and tried to execute again, it didn't happen. because the changed code has to build bundler every time. It's not happened in windows.

Answer (score 0):

I understand this issue is because of that bundler is not getting update every time. I have to update the bundle also before executing the **react-native run-android** command.

To update the build execute this below command

> react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file
>   index.js --bundle-output
>   android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest
>   android/app/src/main/res